# Magento modules

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've got a few questions relating to Magento:

1. From the Magento Admin Panel page, one can find a list
   of Magento modules such as `Mage_Newsletter` and `Mage_poll`
   for instance. I would like to know, where do these come
   from?

   For instance, if I create files such as:

   ```
   /var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/[design_package]/[layout_name]/{layout,templates}
   ```

   What does it take for a module defined by a set of files
   stored in such a directory to show up on the Magento modules list
   at the admnistrative page I just pointed out?
2. Under a design package's skin directory, what is the purpose
   of having an images directory and then a separate `images/media`
   directory. How does one decide what images to put directly
   under the images directory as opposed to under `images/media` ?
   What is the convention used here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.Each module has a module registration file.These registration files exists in

```
app/etc/modules/
```

and these are used to activate or deactivate the module.For example `Mage_Newsletter` registration file is `Mage_Newsletter.xml`

If you want to create a module registration file,create `Namespace_Module.xml` in `app/etc/modules` with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            </codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This module will appear in admin panel.

2.Catalog,static blocks and images that you upload goes under `media`.Theme specific images goes under  `skin/frontend/[design_package]/[layout_name]/images`

If you are new to Magento development,you should checkout [knowledge base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento)

Answer (score 0):

in magento 2.0 while implementing the custom module we have to define the one file in

app\code\PackageName\Modulename\registration.php

this file should have this code

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'PACKAGENAME_MODULENAME',
    **DIR**

so when installing the module using 'php bin/magneto setup:upgrade' ..

this file will be invoked and our module data is registered in magento module configuration file

Answer (score 0):

A. Magento 1.9 and its previous versions,

1.The registration file is put in `yourRootMagentoDirectory/app/etc/modules` folder with name like `Mage_All.xml` (actually it contains most of the core magento module registration info).This file also have Mage_Newsletter and Mage_poll module information

2.The reason is to saperate the image types Foe example Catalog,static blocks and images that you upload goes under media and theme specific images like logo goes under  skin/frontend/[design_package]/[layout_name]/images

B.In magento 2

The registarion file is inside `app/code/[CompanyName]/[moduleName]/registarion.php` file

These files inform magento that these modules are present and magento load these modules.

And for images related,the answer is same in magento2